# Random 6 numbers out of array values>"0"

Tags: php, arrays

I need to list randomly all values larger than zero from this array ($sqla). I tested couple of ways so far, but no success. Any help is highly appreciated. 
The last version was:

```
  $newnum = array_filter(
    $sqla,
    function ($value) {
        return ($value > "0");
    }
while($k=array_rand($newnum))
{
echo $sqla[$k].", ";
```

The array is:

```
array(66) { [0]=> string(2) „15“ [1]=> string(1) „1“ [2]=> string(1) „0“ [3]=> string(1) „0“ [4]=> string(1) „0“ [5]=> string(1) „0“ [6]=> string(1) „0“ [7]=> string(1) „7“ [8]=> string(1) „0“ [9]=> string(1) „0“ [10]=> string(1) „0“ [11]=> string(1) „0“ [12]=> string(1) „0“ [13]=> string(1) „0“ [14]=> string(1) „0“ [15]=> string(1) „0“ [16]=> string(1) „0“ [17]=> string(1) „0“ [18]=> string(1) „0“ [19]=> string(1) „0“ [20]=> string(1) „0“ [21]=> string(1) „0“ [22]=> string(1) „0“ [23]=> string(1) „0“ [24]=> string(1) „0“ [25]=> string(1) „0“ [26]=> string(1) „0“ [27]=> string(1) „0“ [28]=> string(1) „0“ [29]=> string(1) „0“ [30]=> string(1) „0“ [31]=> string(1) „0“ [32]=> string(1) „0“ [33]=> string(1) „0“ [34]=> string(1) „0“ [35]=> string(1) „0“ [36]=> string(1) „0“ [37]=> string(1) „0“ [38]=> string(1) „0“ [39]=> string(1) „0“ [40]=> string(1) „0“ [41]=> string(1) „0“ [42]=> string(1) „0“ [43]=> string(2) „43“ [44]=> string(1) „0“ [45]=> string(1) „0“ [46]=> string(1) „0“ [47]=> string(1) „0“ [48]=> string(1) „0“ [49]=> string(2) „49“ [50]=> string(1) „0“ [51]=> string(1) „0“ [52]=> string(1) „0“ [53]=> string(1) „0“ [54]=> string(1) „0“ [55]=> string(1) „0“ [56]=> string(1) „0“ [57]=> string(1) „0“ [58]=> string(1) „0“ [59]=> string(1) „0“ [60]=> string(1) „0“ [61]=> string(1) „0“ [62]=> string(1) „0“ [63]=> string(3) „649“ [64]=> string(4) „1000“ [65]=> string(19) „2019-01-30 21:33:41“ }
```

The target output is 649,7,49,43,1,1000, randomly echoed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_filter to remove zero values then shuffle the array.
Extract the values with array_slice and echo them with implode to make them comma separated.

```
$newnum = array_filter($newnum);
shuffle($newnum);
echo implode(", ", array_slice($newnum, 0, 6));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!